# How to include String, Integer type information when serializing to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have enabled defaultTyping on my object mapper as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
```

After serialization my JSON string doesn't include type information for `java.lang.*` types (such as `java.lang.String`). I'm guessing this is by design.

The problem I run into, is that during deserialization, there are two methods that match: one that accepts an Enum and another that accepts a String. Of course, Jackson cannot decide which method to use. I was hoping that if the type information were included in the serialization step, this should be a non-issue.

I have already gone down the path of `@JsonIgnore` and Mixins, unfortunately this is not viable.

Any idea how I can get Jackson to deserialize successfully?

Comment: @JsonIgnore or Mixins are the usual way to go. Why is it not viable?

Comment: The amount of Mixins I'll have to build are staggering. It will dirty the test code significantly and not provide enough value to outweigh the amount of time spent building it.